# Целевая аудитория сайтов Stack Exchange

Tags: дефект, статус-проверка, локализация, мобильное-приложение, целевая-аудитория

Беда с падежами в мобильном приложении SO при описании целевой аудитории сайтов:

> [image: программистов]

Для англоязычных сайтов указано:

> professional and enthusiast programmers

Для сайтов русского языка еще и запятая лишняя, но это наверное надо на другой мете отметить.

На web версии для всех вариантов присутствует "For", который вообще нигде не локализован:

> [image: for]

Так что видимо надо это "Для" действительно добавить. Главное, чтобы потом не получился вариант:

> For Для программистов ...

Любопытно, что [японцы](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) как-то умудрились локализовать этот «for»:

> [image: японский for]

Да и на [португальском](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) языке сделано:

> [image: португальский for]

Comment: Возможно, там используется общая строка, которая отображается и в других местах. Я видел фразу наподобие «Welcome to our site for программистов» в UI. Это вполне может быть баг в движке, не учитывающий наличие падежей в неанглийских языках.

Comment: @VladD то есть, предложение склеивается из двух частей, и одна из частей потом используется самодостаточно? Очень похоже на наш случай.

Comment: Ага. Популярная проблема англоязычных интерфейсов. :-\

Comment: Уважаемые, почему нельзя перевести `for` как `для`. Получится Для программистов. Почему вопрос повис в воздухе ? Объясните?

Comment: @stack-it есть несколько причин: 1. проблема считается несущественной; 2. `for` зашита в код и в данном случае не поддаётся локализации. Т.о. возможное решение тривиальной проблемы может быть не совсем тривиальным.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предлагаю вариант оставить падеж как в английской версии и следующий перевод:

> профессиональные программисты и любители

Comment: Поддерживаю вариант про любителей вместо энтузиастов. Как-то менее напыщено звучит. Как новичок говорю.

Comment: Слово любитель также имеет и негативную коннотацию (синоним дилетант).

Comment: @GreenDragon ни разу не синоним. Дилетант может быть как любителем так и профессионалом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, [здесь](https://gallicismes.academic.ru/13744/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) написано иначе.

Comment: @GreenDragon ну ок, синоним. Но экспрессивная окраска у этих слов все равно разная.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, разная. Может мой первый комментарий был не совсем корректен, так как под также я имел ввиду наряду с положительным смыслом(тот кто любит свое дело) имеет и значение с негативной коннотацией. По моим личным наблюдением крайнее значение с каждым годом используется все чаще и чаще.

Answer (score 6):

Видимо, надо сделать описание вида:

> для {КОГО}

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю вариант оставить падеж как в английской версии и следующий перевод:

> профессиональные программисты и энтузиасты

Answer (score 0):

Вариация с энтузиастами, так как необходимо уточнить, энтузиасты чего...

> энтузиасты и профессиональные программисты